# Using WebClient to download string from ASP.NET Web Service Error

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, web-services, webclient

I have a simple ASP.NET Web Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebService1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string Get()
        {
            member mem = new member();
            mem.hello = "hello hello hello";
            mem.kalon = "fafasdf";
            mem.name = "wfasdfawe";
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(mem);
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }

    public class member
    {
        public string hello { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string kalon { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm facing problem to retrieve the string from SilverLight by using WebClient. Can you enlighten me? I uses the below code to get the string from the WebService.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.MyWeb.com/Service1.axms/Get");
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
}

void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
}
```

And I receive error:

System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_1(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)

I have tried this too, still getting the same error:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.MyWeb.com/Service1.axms?op=Get");
wc.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

1 more question:
Is the url like this correct to get the string?

```
http://www.MyWeb.com/Service1.axms?op=Get

http://www.MyWeb.com/Service1.axms/Get
```

Comment: Are you running this with IIS?

Comment: @Rus I tried both IIS and a true Web Hosting Server.

Comment: While using RIA services in Silverlight, I had to put client access policy file, not sure whether you need that one or now.

Comment: Sorry, but are your axms extensions on the service endpoints meant to be asmx instead?